# how to reset primefaces wizard's steps?

Tags: jquery, ajax, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

i use primefaces `<p:wizard>` and i registiration step by step.if registiration is end succesfully,wizard's step is first but if i go on for new record or user,Wizard can not add new record.İt is updating previous record/user instead.How do I add new records in series?
Another problem; when it returned to the first step,it can not to reset the field.how can i do that?
its submit button's code;

```
<p:commandButton immediate="true" value="Submit" update="@parent,wiz1,growl,panel"
                            actionListener="#{OgrenciKayit.save}" oncomplete="wiz.loadStep (wiz.cfg.steps [0], true)" />
```

its returned to the first step if wizard submitted.

```
oncomplete="wiz.loadStep (wiz.cfg.steps [0], true)"
```

and actionListener

```
public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(ogrenci);
        tx.commit();
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Başarılı", "Hoşgeldin :"
                + ogrenci.getAd());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
```

Waiting for your ideas..
(additional information i use Jsf 2.2,Tomcat 7.0.50,Hibernate 4.3.5.final,Primefaces,Shiro)

Comment: i solved my first question When trying random things.i added "session.clear();" in actionListener.now successfully doing.another problem is how to reset the field When wizard returned to first step?thanks a lot

Comment: What PrimeFaces version are you using? In PrimeFaces 5.0, the code in oncomplete won't work. It instead needs to be changed to `PF('wiz').loadStep (PF('wiz').cfg.steps [0], true)`. It was deprecated in 4.0 and removed from 5.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
org.primefaces.context.RequestContext

RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.reset("myForm");
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<p:wizard widgetVar="wiz">
   <p:tab id="tab0">  ...  </p:tab>
   <p:tab id="tab1"> ...
      <p:commandButton value="Jump to tabId"
          actionListener="#{actionTodo.jump}"
          oncomplete="PF('wiz').loadStep('tab0', false)" />
   </p:tab>
 </p:wizard>
```

This works for me on PrimeFaces 5.0. Note you just need to provide the tabId to loadStep method. Also we should call PF with `"PF('widgetVarId')"`.

Comment: I used this in PF 5.3: works great for me.  The widgetVarId needs to be the widgetVar name assigned to the p:wizard element

Comment: I needed both, `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("myForm");` _and_ `onClick="PF('wiz').loadStep('tab0', false)"`. The `onComplete`event was too late for me.

Answer (score 3):

I am using this javascript function and oncomplete handler on submit component:

Submit component:

```
oncomplete="resetWizard(args, PF('wizardWigetVar'));"
```

Javascript:

```
/**
 * Resets the wizard by loading its first step.
 * 
 * @param args
 * @param wizard
 * 
 * @returns
 */
function resetWizard(args, wizard)
{
    if (!args.validationFailed)
    {
        var firstStep = wizard.cfg.steps[0];
        if (wizard.currentStep != firstStep)
            wizard.loadStep(firstStep, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the problem, I had to combine the answers, otherwise whenever I clicked the edit button, the step I stopped in a previous edition was showed.

Controller:

```
public void edit() {
    PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('wizardOrcamento').loadStep('tabCliente', false)");
}
```

XHTML:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{orcamentoController.edit}" [...]>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener [...] />
</p:commandButton>
```

I hope this could help someone.

Comment: Then you have a different invisible problem next to the tab wizard one.

Comment: @Kukeltje no I didn't, it's working really well actually.

Comment: The reason I state this is that this 'combination' should not be needed. What is your PF version?

Answer (score -3):

```
public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(ogrenci);
    tx.commit();
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Başarılı", "Hoşgeldin :"
            + ogrenci.getAd());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
```

> ogrenci = new Ogrenci();

```
}
```